# sed command to add spaces by removing \n

Tags: unix

I have a requirement in which I have one .txt file which contains some lines.

eg. 'a.txt' contains below records
EFG\nABC\nCDE

Now I want the records in the file in following format:
EFG ABC CDE

Basically i want to remove the new line character and replace it with a 'SINGLE SPACE'
Here number of records in the file are not fixed so I have to do it for all records present in the file

Can you please let me know how we can achieve this output using 'sed' command?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sed` here, `tr` will be enough.

```
tr '\n' ' ' <a.txt >b.txt
```

Same with `sed`:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};y/\n/ /' a.txt > b.txt
```

`:a;$!{N;ba}` creates a loop that reads all the lines in, then `y/\n/ /` translates all newlines to spaces.

Comment: Hi..thanks for your reply. But when i am executing this command it is showing me error as 'Label too long: :a;$!{N;ba};y/\n/ /'

can you please provide me the correct code?

Comment: @user3095778 It works with my `sed`; but you can try splitting the command as suggested [here](http://osdir.com/ml/editors.sed.user/2003-11/msg00060.html): `sed -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 'y/\n/ /'`

Comment: Sorry Lev but I am new to this site :( 
so i don't know how to accept an answer..I tried but i am not geeting any button to accept the answer.

Comment: @user3095778 It's the tick to the left of the answer, as described in the link in my previous comment.